# Auth0 RBAC Regular application

Tags: next.js, auth0, rbac

Hello and good day everyone! I am making an application using Next.js and auth0 for authorization and authentication. I wonder how to set users' role by them own. Roles are "admin", "manager" and "worker". I have configured `RBAC` (role based access control) but don't have any idea to set user's role in programmatically way.

I don't have any idea I searched for documentations but I didn't find anything what I want.
I am expecting a codebase like this stuff `setUserRole(user_id, role);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set roles to users with Auth0 UI and API

With the UI:

- Go to Dashboard > User Management > Users.
- Click ... next to the user you want to modify and select Assign Roles.
- Choose the role(s) you wish to assign, then click Assign.

With the API:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://{yourDomain}/api/v2/users/USER_ID/roles' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{ "roles": [ "ROLE_ID", "ROLE_ID" ] }'
```

However, notice that Auth0 roles may sometimes be a bit hard to use, I had issues with calling Auth0 roles API a lot of times to check roles and got to my API quota, so you may want to consider other AuthZ solutions such as [Permit.io](https://permit.io), AuthZed or others.

[In this blog you can see how to do it with Auth0](https://www.permit.io/blog/add-rbac-authorization-to-auth0).

Comment: You can also check this docs there are examples of auth0 API there as well:  https://docs.permit.io/integrations/authentication/auth0/permit-integration/